# boost::geometry::intersection of Polygon and "directed" Polyline

Tags: c++, boost, geometry, boost-geometry

I need to find all intersection points of polyline and polygon such that polyline intersects polygon from outside. I marked such points with bold dots on an attached picture.

The problem is that a `boost::geometry::intersection` returns all intersection points and I need to check the intersection type somehow.

Here is some small example of using `boost::geometry::intersection`:

```
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(Eigen::Vector2d, double, cs::cartesian, x(), y())
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_3D(Eigen::Vector3d, double, cs::cartesian, x(), y(), z())
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_LINESTRING(std::vector<Eigen::Vector2d>)
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_MULTI_LINESTRING(std::vector<std::vector<Eigen::Vector2d>>)

using Point = Eigen::Vector2d;
using Polyline = std::vector<Point>;
using Polygon = boost::geometry::model::polygon<Point>;

Polyline polyline{{0, -10}, {0, 10}};

Polygon polygon;
std::vector<Point> polygon_points{{-1., 1.}, {1., 1.}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}};
boost::geometry::assign_points(polygon, polygon_points);

std::vector<Point> intersection_points;

boost::geometry::intersection(polygon, polyline, intersection_points);

for (const auto& p : intersection_points) {
  std::cout << p << std::endl << std::endl; //  here we have 2 points, but I need only one (0, -1)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it:

Do for each segment of the polyline:

1. get the [`intersection`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersection/intersection_3.html)'s of this segment only and the polygon; (If none then `continue`).
2. use [`within`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/within/within_2.html) to check if the start terminal is inside or outside the polygon;
3. if inside, then append every intersection with an odd-numbered index to the output;
4. if outside, then append every intersection with an even-numbered index (and zero) to the output.

Done.

Comment: Your idea is based on the fact that intersections returned by `intersects` are sorted. But does the `intersects` guarantee this?